# TCPDUMP Syntax filter eth0 traffic to readable file

Tags: pcap, tcpdump

Attempting to capture traffic but I don't know the write syntax to filter the output to a readable pcap file.

I need to use the syntax
**tcpdump -r file.pcap**

and to filter eth0 icmp traffic

**tcpdump -i eth0 icmp -c 10 > file.pcap**

is there a way to do this in one line of command?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but, if you're writing a *pcap* file rather than a *text* file, it doesn't involve the `>` character.

By default, tcpdump captures traffic from an interface, or reads a capture file, and writes out a human-readable dissection of the packets to the standard output.

You need the `-w` flag to write out a pcap file, so, in your case, the command is

```
tcpdump -r file.pcap -w file.pcap ICMP
```

Your command

```
tcpdump -i eth0 icmp -c 10 > file.pcap
```

wouldn't write out a pcap file, it writes out text such as

```
16:30:59.808885 IP 192.168.1.5 > example.com: ICMP echo request, id 40541, seq 0, length 64
16:30:59.841404 IP example.com > 192.168.1.5: ICMP echo reply, id 40541, seq 0, length 64
```

If you wanted to write the ICMP traffic to a pcap file, you would do

```
tcpdump -i eth0 icmp -c 10 -w file.pcap
```